# What does getExternalStorageDirectory() return on the Xoom?

Tags: android

From what I've read, the Motorola XOOM has an SD card slot, but the slot is currently disabled in shipping devices. I'm developing an app that stores data on the SD card, whose path is (as of 2.2) `/mnt/sdcard/`. What does `getExternalStorageDirectory()` return on the XOOM? Will this change when the SD card is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does getExternalStorageDirectory() return on the XOOM?

Literally, it returns `/mnt/sdcard`. However, this points to some on-board storage, much like many other Android devices do. My guess is that they chose `/mnt/sdcard` for greater compatibility with developers who hardwired that value into their apps.

> Will this change when the SD card is enabled?

You are better asking off that question on the [MOTODEV discussion boards](http://community.developer.motorola.com/).